# how to determine length of time based on dates in R?

Tags: r

I am looking to find the difference in years, days, hours, minutes, seconds between 2 dates and times. Each of these 5 would be a new column. The start and end date are in dd/mm/yyyy format. The start and end times are in hh:mm:ss format.

- column 1 should be full years passed between start and end.
- column 2 should be days (after years) passed. (under 364)
- column 3 should be hours after days passed. (under 24)
- column 4 should be minutes after hours passed. (under 60)
- column 5 should be second after minutes passed.

I am unsure how to code this in R. Any help to get started would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`as.numeric(date)` gives `date` in a format of "number of seconds passed since a specific date". So you can turn your dates to seconds and run calculations with that.

Dummy data:

```
date = lubridate::as_datetime(c("2020-08-05 12:00:00","2021-09-30 17:30:25"))
```

Code:

```
date = as.numeric(date)

denominators = c(60*60*24*365, 60*60*24, 60*60, 60, 1) #How many seconds in year, day, hour, minute and second
cols = numeric() #Empty vector to store results
remain = date[2]-date[1] #Starting point for the remainder

for(i in 1:length(denominators)){
  cols[i] = trunc((remain)/denominators[i])
  remain = remain - cols[i]*denominators[i]}
```

You can also name the vector by doing:

```
names(cols) = c("Years","Days","Hours","Minutes","Seconds")
```

Output:

```
> cols
  Years    Days   Hours Minutes Seconds 
      1      56       5      30      25
```

Comment: Not sure how sophisticated the TO wants his calculations, but the fixed conversion with 365 days neglects the fact that there are leapyears, like in 2020. E.g the difference between Feb 28, 2021 and Feb 28, 2020 would give one year and 1 day where, in fact, it's only 1 year and 0 days.

Comment: True, but as he said "(under 364)" for days i assumed that he was willing to accept that mistake. But maybe there is a solution with actual date manipulation packages that overcome this.

Comment: when I try to do as.numeric() with my data, it shows only NA's. Is there a reason this happened?

Comment: Your date is probably not formatted as date, but as a simple string/character (this is probably why you got an error with the other answer also). To correct this, do `date = lubridate::as_datetime(date)` before everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following toy data:

```
dat <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1325646906.47215, 1325939193.94239, 
1326393311.43146, 1326893111.72323, 1329160425.66278, 1329941092.98845, 
1331676913.11139, 1336534476.92816, 1336854219.76095, 1340508976.95104, 
1341988397.40445, 1342874148.29895, 1343922899.76848, 1345423246.12892, 
1347031958.69809, 1350439597.85911, 1351877928.41993, 1351944648.77309, 
1352526175.56524, 1350683308, 1582930108), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), y = structure(c(1367717543.47215, 1332749998.94239, 
1343939119.43146, 1368686228.72323, 1337866340.66278, 1357626373.98845, 
1340861455.11139, 1343305871.92816, 1378155928.76095, 1358484266.95104, 
1359392859.40445, 1355157621.29895, 1372962968.76848, 1364088903.12892, 
1354590155.69809, 1354355821.85911, 1371121585.41993, 1379051036.77309, 
1370987918.56524, 1395436350, 1614552508), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), row.names = c(NA, 21L), class = "data.frame")
```

we can make good use of lubridates date functions. It looks a bit ugly, but does the trick. I didn't check the correct calcualtion for every single date, but it seems to get the difficult ones right (like the last date with a leap year where it correctly calculates 1 year, 0 days).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
dat %>%
  mutate(years   = trunc(time_length(interval(x, y), unit = "years")),
         days    = trunc(time_length(interval(x %m+% years(years), y), unit = "days")),
         hours   = trunc(time_length(interval(x %m+% years(years) %m+% days(days), y), unit = "hours")),
         minutes = trunc(time_length(interval(x %m+% years(years) %m+% days(days) %m+% hours(hours), y), unit = "minutes")),
         seconds = trunc(time_length(interval(x %m+% years(years) %m+% days(days) %m+% hours(hours)  %m+% minutes(minutes), y), unit = "seconds")))
```

which gives:

```
                     x                   y years days hours minutes seconds
1  2012-01-04 03:15:06 2013-05-05 01:32:23     1  120    22      17      17
2  2012-01-07 12:26:33 2012-03-26 08:19:58     0   78    19      53      25
3  2012-01-12 18:35:11 2012-08-02 20:25:19     0  203     1      50       8
4  2012-01-18 13:25:11 2013-05-16 06:37:08     1  117    17      11      57
5  2012-02-13 19:13:45 2012-05-24 13:32:20     0  100    18      18      35
6  2012-02-22 20:04:52 2013-01-08 06:26:13     0  320    10      21      21
7  2012-03-13 22:15:13 2012-06-28 05:30:55     0  106     7      15      42
8  2012-05-09 03:34:36 2012-07-26 12:31:11     0   78     8      56      35
9  2012-05-12 20:23:39 2013-09-02 21:05:28     1  113     0      41      49
10 2012-06-24 03:36:16 2013-01-18 04:44:26     0  208     1       8      10
11 2012-07-11 06:33:17 2013-01-28 17:07:39     0  201    10      34      22
12 2012-07-21 12:35:48 2012-12-10 16:40:21     0  142     4       4      33
13 2012-08-02 15:54:59 2013-07-04 18:36:08     0  336     2      41       9
14 2012-08-20 00:40:46 2013-03-24 01:35:03     0  216     0      54      17
15 2012-09-07 15:32:38 2012-12-04 03:02:35     0   87    11      29      57
16 2012-10-17 02:06:37 2012-12-01 09:57:01     0   45     7      50      24
17 2012-11-02 17:38:48 2013-06-13 11:06:25     0  222    17      27      37
18 2012-11-03 12:10:48 2013-09-13 05:43:56     0  313    17      33       8
19 2012-11-10 05:42:55 2013-06-11 21:58:38     0  213    16      15      43
20 2012-10-19 21:48:28 2014-03-21 21:12:30     1  152    23      24       2
21 2020-02-28 22:48:28 2021-02-28 22:48:28     1    0     0       0       0
```

Comment: When I try this method, it gives me error: "Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `days`. x error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'time_length': character string is not in a standard unambiguous format ℹ Input `days` is `trunc(...)`." Is there a way around this?

Comment: See comment from @Ricardo Semião e Castro. You need to properly formatting you input variables as dates.